# Synchronize dask map_partitions with print functions

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have the following code:

```
def func1(df):
    x = 1
    print('Processing func1')
    return x

def func2(df):
    x = 2
    print('Processing func2')
    return x

ddf = from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

print('func1 processing started')
ddf.map_partitions(func1)
print('func1 processing ended')

print('func2 processing started')
ddf.map_partitions(func2)
print('func2 processing ended')

ddf.compute()
```

What I'm looking for is a way to log (or print in this case) the steps before, during and after each of the map partitions are executed.

However, since the `ddf.compute()` triggers the map_partitions after the print functions, I get something like this:

```
func1 processing started
func1 processing ended
func2 processing started
func2 processing ended
Processing func1
Processing func1
Processing func1
Processing func2
Processing func2
Processing func2
```

Instead, I need

```
func1 processing started
Processing func1
Processing func1
Processing func1
func1 processing ended
func2 processing started
Processing func2
Processing func2
Processing func2
func2 processing ended
```

How to make this work? Note: My example uses `print`, but I would like to synchromize map_partitions with *any* python function.

**UPDATE**

A more realistic scenario:

```
def func1():
   df = dd.read_csv('file.csv', npartitions=3)
   log('In func1') 
   df = func11(df,123)
   log('func1 ended')
   ddf.compute()


def func11(df,x):
    log('In func11')
    # ... do stuff with df
    df = func111(df,x)
    return df 
 

def func111(df, x):
    log('In func111')
    df = df.map_partitions(func1111)
    return df


def func1111(df):
    df['abc'] = df['abc'] * 2
    log('Processing func1111')
    return df

log(msg):
    print(msg) # or log in file or DB
```

The requirement is that this should print:

```
In func1
In func11
In func111
Processing func1111
Processing func1111
Processing func1111
func1 ended
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `ddf` to queue `ddf.map_partitions()` and `log()` with `ddf.persist()` and `wait(ddf)`.

```py
from dask.distributed import wait


class QueuedMapPartitionsWrapper:
    def __init__(self, ddf, queue=None):
        self.ddf = ddf
        self.queue = queue or []

    def map_partitions(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__class__(self.ddf, self.queue + [(True, func, args, kwargs)])

    def log(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__class__(self.ddf, self.queue + [(False, log, args, kwargs)])

    def compute(self):
        ddf = self.ddf
        for (map_partitions, func, args, kwargs) in self.queue:
            if map_partitions:
                ddf = ddf.map_partitions(func, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                ddf = ddf.persist()
                wait(ddf)
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return ddf.compute()
```

Usage 1:

```py
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
ddf = QueuedMapPartitionsWrapper(ddf)

ddf = ddf.log('func1 processing started')
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(func1)
ddf = ddf.log('func1 processing ended')

ddf = ddf.log('func2 processing started')
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(func2)
ddf = ddf.log('func2 processing ended')

ddf.compute()
```

Usage 2:

```py
def func1():
   ddf = dd.read_csv('file.csv', npartitions=3)
   ddf = QueuedMapPartitionsWrapper(ddf)    # Either here

   log('In func1') 

   ddf = func11(ddf, 123)
   # ddf = QueuedMapPartitionsWrapper(ddf)  # or here (just before ddf.log)
   ddf = ddf.log('func1 ended')

   ddf.compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a new function that contains the desired sequence of actions:

```py
def my_flow(df):

    print('func1 processing started')
    df = func1(df)
    print('func1 processing ended')

    print('func2 processing started')
    df = func2(df)
    print('func2 processing ended')
    
    return df

ddf_new = ddf.map_partitions(my_flow)
```

Comment: unfortunately this will not work, the question is a simplification of a more complex code. I was thinking more of using `delay` of the print function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try wrapping your function with a decorator.  If you put your desired logging behavior in a decorator, then you don't have to put a bunch of print statements all over your code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

import time
from functools import wraps


def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        print("Starting :%r" % f.__name__)
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()
        print('Completed :%r took: %2.2f sec' % (f.__name__, te-ts))
        return result
    return wrap


@timing
def func1():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([3000, 10]))
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
    time.sleep(1)
    ddf = func11(ddf, None)
    df = ddf.compute()
    return df


@timing
def func11(ddf, x):
    time.sleep(1)
    ddf = func111(ddf, None)
    return ddf


@timing
def func1111(df):
    df = df * 2
    time.sleep(1)
    return df


@timing
def func111(ddf, x):

    ddf = ddf.map_partitions(func1111)
    time.sleep(1)
    return ddf


ddf = func1()
```

This gives the output:

```
Starting :'func1'
Starting :'func11'
Starting :'func111'
Starting :'func1111'
Completed :'func1111' took: 1.00 sec
Completed :'func111' took: 2.01 sec
Completed :'func11' took: 3.01 sec
Starting :'func1111'
Starting :'func1111'
Starting :'func1111'
Completed :'func1111' took: 1.00 sec
Completed :'func1111' took: 1.00 sec
Completed :'func1111' took: 1.00 sec
Completed :'func1' took: 5.02 sec
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't do what I need, `Completed :'func1'` should be at the end

Comment: @ps0604 I edited the answer to nest the functions as you have in your example.